# How to use layout via ".scaml" in play+play-scalate

Tags: templates, playframework, scalate

I'm using Play frameword and play-scalate plugin.

The default demo of play-scalate provided is only ".ssp", but what I want to use is ".scaml". I create a "default.scaml", but I don't know how to include the inner views.

Maybe my description is not clear, what I want to do is:

translate the the layout "main.html" to "default.scaml".

The content of "main.html" is:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        #{doLayout /}
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to translate `#{doLayout /}`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
-@ var body: String 
-@ var title: String = "Some Default Title"

%html
  %head= title
  %body
    %p hello, everyone
    != body
```